# Name for "Category without nontrivial automorphisms"?

Tags: ct.category-theory

It's all in the title: Is there really no name for categories in which all automorphisms are trivial? I've encountered some examples of these, the most prominent being the simplex category.

Comment: In other places, objects without nontrivial automorphisms are called [rigid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rigid+object). There is already a different notion of [rigid category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rigid+monoidal+category), but I'm of the opinion that that's the wrong adjective and one shouldn't be using this terminology.

Comment: @JohannesHahn In this terminology, should'nt "Rigid category"  mean a category with no non-trivial self equivalences.

Comment: I think Gaunt category (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gaunt+category) is not too far off. It usually refers to the stronger property of having no non-trivial isomorphisms. But a category has no non-trivial automorphism if and only if it is equivalent to a Gaunt category. So maybe "Essentially gaunt category" would be a good name ? (or use "gaunt" and "strictly gaunt")

Comment: I like "essentially gaunt".  Even in the absence of the existing notion of "rigid category", I would expect a "rigid category" to be one that has no automorphisms *itself* as an object of Cat, rather than one whose *objects* have no automorphisms.

Comment: Thank you, all. Maybe my notion of cat without nontrivial automorphisms is too specific to deserve a name (but yes, "essentially gaunt" is good): it seems cats without nontrivial endomorphisms are more common, and called "one-way"; even more common, it seems, are "direct" categories which have no infinite descending chains of non-id morphisms. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up the comments & discussion: no established terminology seems to exist, but *essentially gaunt* would be a good name for categories without nontrivial automorphisms.

For a related notion, categories without notrivial *isomorphisms* are called *gaunt*, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gaunt+category

On the other side, categories without nontrial *endomorphisms* are called *one-way*, and those without *infinite descending chains of non-id morphisms* are called *direct*, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+category